# Angular 5 data binding of custom component does not detect reference change

Tags: angular, data-binding

In my parent component i bind a object property from the child component like this:

```
<app-chid-comp [date]="resultObj.date"></app-child-comp>
```

This is the component file which just observe some service and copy the result to the bound property. I simplified it and `resultObj` is just an object with a date property (string).

```
@Component({
        selector: 'app-parent-comp',
        templateUrl: 'parent.component.html',
        styleUrls: ['./parent.style.scss'],
        changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush
    })
export class ParentComponent implements OnInit {
    public resultObj;

    constructor(private changeDetector: ChangeDetectorRef
                private myService) {}

    ngOnInit() {
        this.changeValue();
    }

   changeValue() {
        myService
            .get()
            .subscribe(result => {
                if (result) {
                    this.resultObject = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(result));
                    this.changeDetector.markForCheck();
                }
            });
    }
}
```

*Imagine that the main part changeValue is called after some time again.*
This is the child component:

```
@Component({
    selector: 'app-child-comp',
    templateUrl: 'child.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./child.style.scss']
})
export class ChildComponent {
    public mydate: any;

    constructor() {}

    @Input()
    set date(date: any) {
        this.mydate = date;
    }

    get date() {
        return this.mydate;
    }
}
```

**Here comes my question**: Why is "date" initiality set if angular renders the component but then never again? 
I thought i can change the reference with `JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(value))` 
and to be sure trigger that with the `this.changeDetector.markForCheck()`?

I'll then tried to bound a string property from parent component to the child and changed it after some time again. The result was that i never got the change in the child component. I then used the `Object.assign({}, value)` and got this change. But if i use an object and try to bind a property from this object this approach doesn't worked.

Comment: inject `ChangeDetectorRef` and call `detectChanges()` after assignment in your component

Comment: please check my solution and feedback me, thanks.

Comment: Thanks. I implemented and test your solution but it does not work. Injected in the child component the change detector and called in ngOnInit the detectChanges() method. Is this correct?

Comment: not in `ngOnInit()` function, use this after data binding

Comment: try this: `<app-chid-comp *ngIf="resultObj != null" [date]="resultObj.date"></app-child-comp>`

Comment: Thanks again, i tried both but sadly it has no effect